# Azure Custom Translator. The model got automatically undeployed after a certain amount of time

Tags: azure, model, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure Custom Translator to set up the custom dictionary. I can train the model and use it through the category id with no issues. However, approximately after around 6 hours, the model is getting undeployed, and as a result, API also doesn't work. I can deploy the model again, and then it works fine still for several hours. Why does this happen? Any thought appreciated.